Separate default configurations and my own changes with a layered FS : /Data/etc/ upper layer in RO and /etc/ lower layer in RW?
I wish to separate the default packages configuration files (/etc/), and the configuration files I edited e.g. in /Data/etc/ (normally should be /usr/local/etc/, but let assume /Data/etc/).
This to enable me to easily see the modifications I made, to easily back it up, etc.
Therefore, I was wondering it was possible to mount /etc/ as :

upper layer FS in RO : /Data/etc/
lower layer FS in RW : itself (/etc/).

The package manager would make its changes in /etc/ like normal.
But when I add a file in /Data/etc/, e.g. /Data/etc/foo, I wish to then have a /etc/foo file in RO that will shadow any existing /etc/foo.
Note:

physical links aren't possible as /Data and /etc will be in different FS.
symbolic links would be troublesome : e.g. if a symlink is deleted when updating a package, requires to automatically create a symlink for each files in /Data/etc/, etc.
mount --bind would be troublesome for the same reason.
some packages does look at /usr/local/etc/ for extra-configuration files, but unfortunately, not all.

However, I failed to see how to do so with UnionFS/AuFS/OverlayFS/etc.
I am also open to alternative solutions/ideas.

Consider using a Linux based on Containers.  See CoreOS or natively Ubuntu >=24.04.  I wrote an answer there to "turn off" SNAP packages.  Fedora uses Flatpaks.  Same concept Different Name.  The data in what you call the lower layer is the OS.  The /etc files inside the Flatpak/SNAP are your Upper Layer.   Config information for the Flatpak/SNAP is fetched from your lower layer and used while the app inside the Container running in your upper layer

You've said you want the package manager to make its changes like normal, but also that your configuration files shadow those of /etc, so what do you expect to happen when the package manager tries to change the shadow file? What you are trying to implement is interesting. You might want to consider using git on your /etc :) Then automatically commiting after a package manager change (you know what files belong to the package manager using dpkg -S)

@arielmarcovitch "so what do you expect to happen when the package manager tries to change the shadow file?"
=> For now, I though to prevent the package manager from editing files I manually edited (hence the RO), in order to prevent it from reverting a change I made.

@eyoung100 Thanks for your answer, I didn't knew snap package were container.
As far as I understand, snap are more for desktop app, and docker for server app. But for "core" configuration, /etc/ is still used (e.g. network, SSH, bash).

Something like what you’re after is coming in systemd v256, systemd-confext. However that might not be usable for you for a while yet.
Looking at the broader issue of tracking configuration changes (and identifying their origin as a subset of that), perhaps you could use a tool such as etckeeper. This is available in most distributions, and will integrate with the package manager to record changes made to /etc as separate commits. You can then record your own changes as separate commits — this can serve as a journal too, since you’ll have room in the commit messages to record the reasons for each change.
Changing a couple of configuration settings will improve your experience with etckeeper, in etckeeper.conf:

assuming you’re using the git backend, GIT_COMMIT_OPTIONS can be used to specify options used with git when run by etckeeper; you might be able to use this for example to set the commit authorship to distinct values;
AVOID_DAILY_AUTOCOMMITS=1 disables daily autocommits; this ensures that any manual changes that haven’t been committed yet don’t end up included in an automatic commit;
AVOID_COMMIT_BEFORE_INSTALL=1 disables automatic commits before installation; this serves a similar purpose to the previous setting, but prior to package installations rather than as part of daily processing.

With the above, changes you make will be readily apparent in git logs and blames, and if you forget to commit a change, package manager operations will be aborted instead of being allowed to make further changes.
etckeeper is available in most distributions, and distribution packages of etckeeper configure it to integrate with the distribution’s package manager.

GIT_COMMIT_OPTIONS= configuration doesn't work properly :
--author 'test <>' gives fatal: --author ''test' n'est pas de la forme 'Nom <email>' ni ne correspond à aucun auteur existant
-c user.name='test' gives fatal: Une seule option parmi -c/-C/-F/--fixup peut être utilisée..
I think we have to use GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="toto" GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="<>" etckeeper commit "test" instead.

You can use "<>" for an empty e-mail address. Putting one doesn't change the error message. It seems etckeeper has a bug cutting the option at the second space.
